# Transferring a zip to ec2 via local ssh key

Tags: windows, ssh, terraform

Using below code to zip a directory (works) and transfer it to the ec2 host using ssh.

```
data "archive_file" "scripts" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir = "${path.module}/files/app"
  output_path = "${path.module}/files/app.zip"
}

resource "null_resource" "upload" {
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = data.archive_file.scripts.output_path
    destination = "/home/${var.ec2_user}/${data.archive_file.scripts.output_path}"

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = var.ec2_user
      private_key = file("C:/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa.ppk")
      host        = var.hostname
    }
  }
}
```

However I get the following error:

`Error: Failed to read ssh private key: no key found`

How do I use a local ssh key to transfer the zip to the remote host?

The files are small, should I be using provisioner?

Thanks

Comment: Depending upon what those files are, this may be better use case for Packer or user data. Both would be much easier too.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Failed to read ssh private key: no key found

That error means that no private key was found in the file specified.

In the following line of your example, you are specifying a private key in Putty format.

```
private_key = file("C:/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa.ppk")
```

Terraform expects private keys to be RSA or ECDSA PEM files. Your SSH server might only support RSA. Newer SSH servers usually support both RSA and ECDSA.

If you created your private key with OpenSSL, then the private key filename defaults to `id_rsa`. If that file exists, change your Terraform to:

```
private_key = file("C:/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa")
```